# How do I detect that a picture is being taken with a front-facing camera in android? Trying to fix flipping horizontally of picture

Tags: android, image, camera

Code:

```
public void buttonLogic() {
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("Taking a picture!");
        //create intent and send picture through intent as extra, created as temp file on device
        final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(getApplicationContext())));
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
});
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
            final File file = getTempFile(this);
            try {
                //retrieve bitmap for picture taken
                Bitmap originalBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));
                Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
                //get exif data and orientation to determine auto-rotation for picture
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface("" + file);
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
                //rotate picture certain # of degrees depending on orientation then sets new matrix
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                switch (orientation) {
                    case 3:
                        matrix.postRotate(180);
                        rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, originalBitmap.getWidth(), originalBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        matrix.postRotate(90);
                        rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, originalBitmap.getWidth(), originalBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        matrix.postRotate(270);
                        rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, originalBitmap.getWidth(), originalBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        break;
                }

                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PictureActivity.class);
                //assigns to global bitmap variable then goes to intent
                GlobalClass.img = rotatedBitmap;
                startActivity(i);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
       }
   }
 }
```

I've been able to adjust the picture if it gets automatically rotated using `EXIF` data. But when I take a picture with the `front-camera` it flips it horizontally. How do I detect if the picture was taken with the `front-facing` camera so I can flip it back. I have code to flip it back done but not to detect properly if the front-camera was used. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617735/detect-if-image-was-taken-with-front-camera

Comment: @mithun no solutions found in that post that worked. have already read it.